# SQL Server 2008 Management studio - can't see tables, can run queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-permissions

Well, I have a database running on shared hosting and have successfully connected to it. However, i cannot see the database but when i run i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Item
```

`Item` is a table in it, i get correct result.

Further more, when connected via `Visual Studio 2010` with the same credentials, i see it.

Comment: Do you have `view definition` permission on the table?

Comment: Have you connected the object explorer?

Comment: Yes, i have `View definition` permission and yes, i am connected :)

Comment: i think you should restart and check it again

Comment: When you open the tables folder do you get an error message or simply not see anything there?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot see"? Do you mean it doesn't appear in the Object Explorer tree? Or it's not in the dropdown? Can you see some databases but not others?

Comment: I can not see it in Object Explorer tree but can run queries and create tables...

Answer (score 1):

Ive had this issue before and resolved it by applying the current Service Pack to SSMS

Comment: tnx. i will try this :) but we've already migrate it to SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/387616/tables-node-does-not-show-all-schemas-in-ssmse-2008